# After copying pdf to pdf a new paragraph added to destination is flipped

Tags: java, itext

When I create a new pdf document and add paragraph, it is OK.
When I copy sourcePDF to a new PDF document and after that add a new paragraph,
it is flipped.
I know that if I create a new pdf doc with text and merge with dest documents, it will be ok,
but I hope there is simple solution.
So here is my code.

```
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.PdfCanvas;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Canvas;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.borders.SolidBorder;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.properties.BaseDirection;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;


 public void copyPdfToPdf(String text, String inputPdf, String outputPdf) throws IOException, DocumentException {


PdfDocument pdfDocInput = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(inputPdf));
    Document docInput = new Document(pdfDocInput);
    PdfDocument pdfDocOutput = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outputPdf));
    Document docOutput = new Document(pdfDocOutput);
    
    pdfDocInput.copyPagesTo(1, pdfDocInput.getNumberOfPages(), pdfDocOutput);
         Paragraph p = new Paragraph().add(text);
         
         docOutput.add(p);
         

    docOutput.close();
    docInput.close();
}
```

[image]

How to change document transformation to write a new paragraf in right direction not flipped

I find out this

> [Adding page number text to pdf copy gets flipped/mirrored with itext 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52743566/adding-page-number-text-to-pdf-copy-gets-flipped-mirrored-with-itext-7)

but I did not resolve a problem.

Comment: Can you share the source pdf you're copying from for analysis? Without it I'd assume the method in the answer to the question you linked should work for you.

Comment: I have tested with several kind of pdf.

Comment: I have tested with several kind of pdf.
src document created with microsoft print to pdf
%PDF-1.5
%µí®ű
4 0 obj
<< /Length 5 0 R
   /Filter /FlateDecode
>>
endstream
endobj
startxref
116896
%%EOF

Destination - copy 
%PDF-1.7
%âăĎÓ
5 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 2545>>stream
................
0000127151 00000 n 
trailer
<</ID [<76c32d......3e9c3eda3a81b2c><76c32dde4f7fb48b...............da3a81b2c>]/Info 3 0 R/Root 1 0 R/Size 62>>
%iText-Core-8.0.2
startxref
127569
%%EOF
maybe is ease to merge two pdf, then to flip horizontal paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are creating the document randomly without establishing specific settings, characteristics, or properties. This usually results in *random* results instead of consistent ones.

You have two options.

1. Rotate the document.
2. Rotate the text.

Please note the assumptions.

1. You must know your document orientation and size.

Sources:

1. https://kb.itextpdf.com/it5kb/how-to-rotate-a-paragraph
2. https://kb.itextpdf.com/itext/how-to-rotate-a-page-while-creating-a-pdf-document

Comment: Like he said, if mirror is the issue, he could mirror the text for example with: `PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(output));
        pdfDoc.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.LEGAL);
        pdfDoc.addFont(calibri);
        LineMirroring mirroring = new LineMirroring(pdfDoc.getDefaultPageSize(), fontName,9);`

Comment: here are files https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1lNZ-8OsTm0IksoZ192ftYlzC3r4sRCkQ?usp=sharing
file 11 is source and file 11-2 is destination

Answer (score 0):

Instead pdfDocInput.copyPagesTo... I simple create a new PdfDocument(reader, writer)
After that I add paragraph at fixed position.

```
 PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputPdf);
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(outputPdf);
            PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);
            Document docOutput = new Document(pdfDocument);
            
            File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:fonts/FreeSans.ttf");
                 String FONT =  file.getAbsolutePath();
                 PdfFont freeUnicode = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FONT, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);
                 freeUnicode.getFontProgram();

                 PdfPage newPage = pdfDocument.getFirstPage();
                 int numberOfPages = pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages();        
                 Rectangle pageSize = newPage.getCropBox();
                 
                 Paragraph p = new Paragraph()
                        .setFixedPosition(numberOfPages, pageSize.getWidth()/2, 50, pageSize.getWidth()/2)
                       .setFont(freeUnicode).setFontSize(9)
                       .add(tekst);
                 docOutput.add(p);
         

            pdfDocument.close();
            docOutput.close();
```

Comment: If this works, the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52757913/1729265) you referred to in your question should also have worked unless there is something really weird about your source PDFs.